# How to nested loop in Groovy and get desired final output

Tags: groovy

I want to get the desired output from the below logic. The output should be a key-value pair.

I'm looping the `apiList` and appending the apiList `<value>` to input details `<key>`. If input details contains `v1`, the key is appended as `(success_api.tenantId.host.v1:http)`:

```
class azureConfig {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String  inputDetails = """version=v1 host=http port=80"""
    def inputList = inputDetails.split("\\s")

    def id= "tenantId"
    def apiList = [{api = success_api}, {api = fail_api}]
    def keyValue = ""
      
      for(String item: inputList){
        def path = item.split("=")
          keyValue += id + "." + path[0] + "::" + path[1] + "\n"
         }
      println(keyValue)
    }
}
```

Output should be:

```
success_api.tenantId.host.v1::http
success_api.tenantId.port.v1::80
fail_api.tenantId.host.v1::http
fail_api.tenantId.port.v1::80
```

I have got this ouput for above logic:

```
tenantId.version::v1
tenantId.host::http
tenantId.port::80
```

Comment: what is `a key-value pair` in your understanding? Your code also doesn't make much sense, as you are not looping thru `appList`, but rather `inputList`, and `appList` is not used at all

Comment: What is the purpose of `apiList` which is shown as a `List` of `Closure` instances (`[{api = success_api}, {api = fail_api}]`) which are never invoked?

Comment: We need to loop first appList after that we should call nested loop for inputList and frame a above output. My logic I was called only inputList.

Comment: @MohanK The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/75296588/3533584 points out the same `Closure` issue.  It looks like you believe those are `Map` instances, but they are `Closure` instances.