# How to Iterate array of objects in groovy

Tags: groovy

How to loop the array of objects in groovy?

I have tried below logic and got the No such property error.

```
def map = [{asset_key = helloWorld}, {asset_key = Demo}]

for(key in map){
  println(key.asset_key)
}
```

error:

> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: asset_key for class: maingroovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: asset_key for class: mainat main.run(main.groovy:4)

expected output:

```
helloWorld
Demo
```

Comment: Do you have a slight idea on what this is supposed to mean `{asset_key = helloWorld}`?

Comment: {asset_key = helloWorld} is key-value pair

Comment: in what language? It's useless to explain anything to you right now. You should really take your time and start with basics of Groovy and Java

Answer (score 0):

The code `{asset_key = helloWorld}` is **not** a Groovy key-value pair, it's a closure. Try this instead:

```
def map = [ asset_key1: 'helloWorld', asset_key2:'Demo']
println "map is: ${map}\n"

map.each { key, value ->
    println "$key has value $value"
}
```

Running the above example will give you this result:

[image]

The following code will give your desired output:

```
def map = [ asset_key1: 'helloWorld', asset_key2:'Demo']

map.each { key, value ->
    println value
}
```